# Scraping data where classes start the same but end different

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am learning Web Scraping and I am trying to get all the jobs listings. All the different job listing are in an a tag and the class all start with 'tapItem fs-unmask result' but then differ how can i scrape for when classes contain 'tapItem fs-unmask result' and not just the exact class name. My code is below although I am copying from a tutorial so I'm sure it's right just that they are scraping from a different website

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = 
requests.get('https://uk.indeed.com/jobs? q=python&l=Bonnyrigg&sort=date&vjk=79b56b0a7deea1aa').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
jobs = soup.find_all('a', #where class = tapItem fs-unmask result  )
print(jobs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html_text = requests.get('https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q=python&l=Bonnyrigg&sort=date&vjk=79b56b0a7deea1aa').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')

jobs = soup.find_all('a',class_=lambda value: value and value.startswith("tapItem fs-unmask result"))
print(jobs)
```

Comment: Thats worked. Thanks